# setup aws certification for a web page

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate

I have a web page i would like to work with ssl (https)

for now it is working but with the private certification which alerts the user of "connection is not secure".

I issued a aws certification by following the link :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html#dns-add-cname

And set my tomcat server to work with certificate by as shown in this link
http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/

but i can not seem to get ride of the "connection is not secure" issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The blog post is too old around 11 years. not sure it working or not.

But you can generate a new free certificate using `AWS Certificate Manager` [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request.html) and add it to load balancer for terminate SSL connection.Your servers will be behind of that load balancers.

Answer (score 0):

On AWS ACM you will need to have a load balancer in front of your web server, you can then terminate the SSL at the load balancer and forward HTTP connections to your tomcat webserver:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

Alternatively if you don't want to have a load balancer (cost etc), then you can look at using a free CA, such as letsencrypt. I've never used letsencrpt with tomcat before but a quick google came up with a few sensible solutions e.g. https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/configuring-lets-encrypt-with-tomcat-6-x-and-7-x/32416

Once up and running with SSL I suggest you check how strong your SSL config is using https://www.ssllabs.com/

Comment: hey , as you suggested , i added a load balancer, set the listener to work with https and the certificate i issued earlier.  on the target i specified the tomcat server. however , if i direct the load balancer to direct to the https port of the tomcat server it still requests the certificate , but if i direct it to the http port it returns 502 bad gateway and returns on log Error parsing HTTP request header , org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process

Comment: Are you able to hit the tomcat server on HTTP without the load balancer being there? Could your app running on tomcat have some dependency on terminating the SSL itself?

Comment: If I approach my server directly I can connect to it via http and https, 
with the load balancer i can configure from http to http or https to https(without resolving the cert issue). 
As I understand it, I should set the load balancer to work with https and transfer the data to my server's 
http socket. that is not working! and i do not think it is an issue of my server terminating SSL 
as it supposed to get the request on its http socket and not its https socket.